# get value into query from edit mode in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a simple gridview, 2 columns.  The first column is a numeric value.  The second column is based on a selected value from a drop down list.  I have the drop down list working, but when I go to update the table, I get an error :
**Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index**

The offending line is 55

```
Line 53:         {
Line 54:             string BU = (gvSummary.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("dlBU") as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value;
Line 55:             string AnnoNum = gvSummary.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
```

and here is the code behind for the webform:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Configuration;

namespace SHCAnnotation
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                this.BindData();
            }
        }

        protected void EditSummary(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            gvSummary.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            BindData();
        }

        protected void CancelEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
        {
            gvSummary.EditIndex = -1;
            BindData();
        }

        protected void RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && gvSummary.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex)
            {
                DropDownList dlBU = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("dlBU");
                string query = "select distinct Unit from vw_KmartBU";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
                dlBU.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
                dlBU.DataTextField = "Unit";
                dlBU.DataValueField = "Unit";
                dlBU.DataBind();
                //dlBU.Items.FindByValue((e.Row.FindControl("lblBU") as Label).Text).Selected = true;
            }
        }

        protected void UpdateSummary(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            string BU = (gvSummary.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("dlBU") as DropDownList).SelectedItem.Value;
            string AnnoNum = gvSummary.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SRM_MetricConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
            {
                string query = "update vw_GridviewSource set [Business Unit] = @BU where [Annotation Number] = @AnnoNum";
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BU", BU);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AnnoNum", AnnoNum); 


                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
                }
            }
        }




        private void BindData()
        {
            string query = "select [Annotation Number], [Business Unit] as Unit from vw_GridviewSource";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
            gvSummary.DataSource = GetData(cmd);
            gvSummary.DataBind();
        }

        private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
        {
            string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SRM_MetricConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        return dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

What I need to do is get the value in first column "Annotation Number" and use it in the where clause of my update.  So I would need update vw_GridviewSource set [Business Unit] = 'Accessories' where [Annotation Number] = '123456'

Accessories would have been the selection from the drop down list and 123456 would have been in the text box when I selected that row for editing.

Answer (score 0):

Your gridview is missing `DataKeyNames`. It may look like:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSummary" 
    runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="AnnoNum, MyOtherKey1, MyOtherKey2"
    ... ... ...
```

DataKeyNames property is an array of strings. You can find more in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames.aspx)

Comment: Can I specify more than one?  I have a gridview that has multiple columns that identify the unique row in the database.